# Colobot crashes half a second after launching!

Tags: linux, colobot

I want to play colobot on my linux machine but it crashes after 1/2 second later.
Here's gdb dump:

```
Starting program: /usr/games/colobot 
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".

** (zenity:4874): WARNING **: Error retrieving accessibility bus address: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.a11y.Bus was not provided by any .service files
3.14.0
[INFO]: Colobot starting
[INFO]: Creating CApplication
[INFO]: Error on parsing profile: No such node (Resources.Data)
[INFO]: Using datadirs: /usr/share/games/colobot
[INFO]: Error on parsing profile: No such node (Language.Lang)
[INFO]: Opening audio device...
[INFO]: Done.
[INFO]: CApplication created successfully
[New Thread 0x7fffe8bc2700 (LWP 4878)]
[New Thread 0x7ffff7fb9700 (LWP 4877)]
[New Thread 0x7fffeafa6700 (LWP 4876)]
[INFO]: Error on parsing profile: No such node (Setup.Resolution)
[INFO]: Creating CDevice
[INFO]: Auto-detecting VBO support
[INFO]: Detected ARB_vertex_buffer_object extension - using VBOs
[INFO]: CDevice created successfully
[INFO]: Error on parsing profile: No such node (Gamer.LastName)
[INFO]: Error on parsing profile: No such node (Setup.Resolution)
[INFO]: Simulation speed = 1,00

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007ffff2349ca9 in ?? () from /usr/lib/nvidia-340/libnvidia-glcore.so.340.76
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007ffff2349ca9 in ?? ()
   from /usr/lib/nvidia-340/libnvidia-glcore.so.340.76
#1  0x00007ffff20773e0 in ?? ()
   from /usr/lib/nvidia-340/libnvidia-glcore.so.340.76
#2  0x00007ffff1fc8972 in ?? ()
   from /usr/lib/nvidia-340/libnvidia-glcore.so.340.76
#3  0x00007ffff1fca068 in ?? ()
   from /usr/lib/nvidia-340/libnvidia-glcore.so.340.76
#4  0x00007ffff1fca719 in ?? ()
   from /usr/lib/nvidia-340/libnvidia-glcore.so.340.76
#5  0x00007ffff20389ee in ?? ()
   from /usr/lib/nvidia-340/libnvidia-glcore.so.340.76
#6  0x00007ffff2035a03 in ?? ()
   from /usr/lib/nvidia-340/libnvidia-glcore.so.340.76
#7  0x00007ffff20c3ff6 in ?? ()
   from /usr/lib/nvidia-340/libnvidia-glcore.so.340.76
#8  0x00007ffff20c41b0 in ?? ()
   from /usr/lib/nvidia-340/libnvidia-glcore.so.340.76
#9  0x00007ffff20c48b2 in ?? ()
   from /usr/lib/nvidia-340/libnvidia-glcore.so.340.76
#10 0x00007ffff20c4c5f in ?? ()
   from /usr/lib/nvidia-340/libnvidia-glcore.so.340.76
#11 0x00007ffff20c52b8 in ?? ()
---Type <return> to continue, or q <return> to quit---
   from /usr/lib/nvidia-340/libnvidia-glcore.so.340.76
#12 0x00007ffff1fcbe52 in ?? ()
   from /usr/lib/nvidia-340/libnvidia-glcore.so.340.76
#13 0x00007ffff1fcc12c in ?? ()
   from /usr/lib/nvidia-340/libnvidia-glcore.so.340.76
#14 0x00007ffff1fe4644 in ?? ()
   from /usr/lib/nvidia-340/libnvidia-glcore.so.340.76
#15 0x00007ffff1fe5d3c in ?? ()
   from /usr/lib/nvidia-340/libnvidia-glcore.so.340.76
#16 0x00007ffff2087c22 in ?? ()
   from /usr/lib/nvidia-340/libnvidia-glcore.so.340.76
#17 0x00007ffff20882da in ?? ()
   from /usr/lib/nvidia-340/libnvidia-glcore.so.340.76
#18 0x00007ffff1d4e90b in ?? ()
   from /usr/lib/nvidia-340/libnvidia-glcore.so.340.76
#19 0x00007ffff1d4ee52 in ?? ()
   from /usr/lib/nvidia-340/libnvidia-glcore.so.340.76
#20 0x00000000004e82a5 in Gfx::CGLDevice::CreateTexture(ImageData*, Gfx::TextureCreateParams const&) ()
#21 0x00000000004e8d32 in Gfx::CGLDevice::CreateTexture(CImage*, Gfx::TextureCreateParams const&) ()
#22 0x000000000049ccb8 in Gfx::CEngine::UpdateGroundSpotTextures() ()
#23 0x000000000049e16a in Gfx::CEngine::Draw3DScene() ()
---Type <return> to continue, or q <return> to quit---
#24 0x000000000049e5f0 in Gfx::CEngine::Render() ()
#25 0x00000000004604bd in CApplication::Render() ()
#26 0x0000000000463804 in CApplication::Run() ()
#27 0x000000000045c0d1 in main ()
```

From my perspective it is OGLs/drivers fault or messed up shader programs.
Can someone help me out?

Comment: Seems like it could be an Nvidia driver bug.  Are you stuck on the 340.76 driver for your card, or could you move up to a more recent version?

Comment: Yes I am stuck. I'm using a obsolete GPU that means no more updates from Nvidia.

Comment: However the issue was fixed when reinstalling the driver on ubuntu update center.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was the driver.
Try reinstalling or updating see if it works. I know it worked for me :)

Comment: +amaranth Thanks, didn't know that ;)